# SSL Protocol mismatch using tomcat7:deploy

Tags: maven, tomcat, hudson

I have a Hudson CI job setup for deployment to Apache Tomcat. If Tomcat server is restricted to accept only TLSv1.2 protocol, I get a protocol mismatch type of error.

If I put JVM into debug for SSL on my Hudson job I can see that TLSv1 is still being attempted:

```
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 163
main, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, protocol_version
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
```

I have tried to use https.protocols=TLSv1.2 with my mvn parameters but still TLSv1 is given during client hello. At this point I am not sure where else I could look to force TLSv1.2.